# Fatal Error PHP won't seem to go away

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, php-7

**NOT A DUPLICATE**

I am building a local WordPress website using XAMPP as my server. When trying to run my website, I get the follow error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testwordpress.com\wp-includes\cache.php on line 548

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

I added the `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`to my config file as well as changing the php.ini memory limit too `memory_limit = 256M`.

I restarted my server, cleared my cashe and the website still throws this error. Please help :(

EDIT: I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680244/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate) and this did not fix my problem.

Comment: I like that you attempted to solve running out of RAM at 256M by *reducing* the limit to 128. Not sure what you thought that would accomplish...

Comment: Well have you got a custom theme or code ? You probably have a really big object being created through a bad foreach loop or something...