# php memory on nginx doesnt work on increase on anything tricky

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

fyi this question is duplicate and many people ask to but i have collect all answer into my question what i did still on problem or doesnt work but i explain more detail and i want to know why.
similar on

1. [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680244/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)
   and other have much response tell its duplicate and anything.

the case is
i have 3 server ( engine ) where run an application ( **laravel** web ).

A. my engine ( work/no error ): ( apache Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS )

```
❯ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7976         865         497          18        6613        6797
Swap:             0           0           0
```

**B.** my engine ( doesnt work/error allocate memory ): ( nginx ) ( Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS )

```
➜  ~ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7975         658        4312          22        3005        7006
Swap:          4095           1        4094
```

C. my engine ( doesnt work/error allocate memory ): ( nginx ) ( Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS )

```
~ » free -m                                                                                                                                         ~  
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1987        1096         112         131         778         568
Swap:             0           0           0
```

what i do is run a query thats export a excel file where the data is from application is build until now , so need a big memory, time or processing. if see on yesterday there is have 9000 data/row.

what i was do ( with my three server )

1. increase configuration about memory on nginx/apache
2. tried override the setting on .httaccess/file.php/index.php to increase the memory processing
3. tunning mysql oracle/mysql mariadb

my server **(B)** on doesnt work is here :
(my configuration)

```
➜  ~ locate php.ini   
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-production.cli
/usr/lib/php/8.1/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/8.1/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/8.1/php.ini-production.cli

➜  ~ php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

then i modified the php memory

```
// [ 1 ]
// /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit=512M // i have tried set to 2048M or -1 or 99999999999M
```

then i restart the php and nginx for measure ...

```
➜  ~ sudo service nginx restart && sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
➜  ~ nginx -s reload
```

nothing error but still on problem allocate memory stuck on 16384 bytes
so i tried override the setting on `index.php` its on **laravel/index.php** and **laravel/public/index.php**
i put these code and paste into .php file.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 360);
```

still on problem .
what i was debug is when i tried to set the memory only 512M its alert is guide me to increase more memory (  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) ) but when i tried increase into 2048M the alerts is a different ( Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes)

so we can close understand here
for first

1. please try allocate more 20480 bytes
   for second
2. please try allocate more 16384 bytes.

> can anyone explain why ? stuck on 16384 bytes ... what ever i increase to the maximum.

but on my first server with apache its work on configuration and tricky of override instead of index.php apache is use .htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

You edited `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` as I did understand it. This is only the config file for your php cli.

Nginx is using `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`

You need to alter your memory limit there

Comment: i was tried edit all of my php.ini where ever the `php -i | grep php.ini` say my php is `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` or `php --version is. 7.4` , but still didnt work . stuck on stuck on 16384 bytes and when i tried modified the php.ini its show different alert thats mean i think i right on my change when i measure what or where my php.ini is used

Comment: it shows you that because you're executing php from your command line.
NGINX is using a different configuration. This is the one i linked with the fpm keyword